# Tensorflow save and load model/estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

Im super new to tensorflow, and I`m following the tutorials on its webpage.
I already understood the code for the MNIST Dataset tutorial, but I would like to save the model so I can load it afterwards and test it against my own image set.
Im tried many ways of saving it but i keep failing.
Im talking about [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers) tutorial.

Any help will be appreciated!

Edit: Everywhere I go, I see a Session variable, but in this example I dont, and that confuses me...

Do you know how can I save the model from the tutorial and reuse it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @EvanWeissburg I dont know how to save the model in the tutorial I linked. Can you help me?

Comment: Here is the answer to your question, go to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50612923/tensorflow-export-estimators-for-prediction)