# Tensorflow export estimators for prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I wonder how can I export the estimator and then import it for prediction from MNIST tutorial, [Tensorflow's page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/layers/cnn_mnist.py).
Thank you!

Comment: Here is detailed example with latest tensorflow version 1.7
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52222383/5904928

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Estimator` has `model_dir` args where the model will be saved. So during prediction we use the `Estimator` and call the `predict` method which recreates the graph and the checkpoints are loaded.

For the `MNIST` example, the prediction code would be:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

# An input-function to predict the class of new data.
predict_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x": eval_data},
    num_epochs=1,
    shuffle=False)

mnist_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
      model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/mnist_convnet_model")

#Prediction call
predictions = mnist_classifier.predict(input_fn=predict_input_fn)

pred_class = np.array([p['classes'] for p in predictions]).squeeze()
print(pred_class)

# Output
# [7 2 1 ... 4 5 6]
```

Comment: how do I know which key words the prediction has? For example, if I want to get the probabilities instead of classes, can I check if probabilities keyword is given?