# restore model tf.estimator.DNNClassifier

Tags: tensorflow

```
model = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feat_cols, hidden_units=[1024, 512, 256])
model.train(input_fn=input_func,steps=5000)
```

This create check point

I comeback day 2; now I need my model from check point; how to restore?

```
sess=tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(file_path + "/" + "model.ckpt-1000.meta")
saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint(file_path))
model = ????? -- how do I get my model back?
```

Comment: Check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50612923/tensorflow-export-estimators-for-prediction/50613631#50613631

Comment: Here is detailed example with latest tensorflow version 1.7
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52222383/5904928

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why I struggled.  Answer to be rather simple.  Read Article on Checkpoints: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/checkpoints

Very simple code to reload your model:

```
model_load = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feat_cols, hidden_units=[10, 10, 10, 10], model_dir="C:/Users/AI101~1/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpm2ndcvf_")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck at the same problem for a whole day, on How to run inference from saved checkpoints and graphs. Almost all of the suggestions are to load the graph using .meta file, and freeze it to some .pb file. I tried those approaches, they were working in the examples but were failing in my case for one reason or another. Also, being new to TF, couldn't make much sense out of it.

So, I just did some hit and trials(after4-5 hours web sniffing) to load the model same way as during training, and to my surprise it worked.
*You will need your **training script/Estimator or Model Function** to load the model.*

```
test_data = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(<input_feed_dict/x=np.array(something)>, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)
model = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=<Your_Estimator_Function>, model_dir="<model_dir>")

predictions = model.predict(input_fn=test_data)
```

On a side note, After going through so many links I can say that there is no proper documentation available(especially for beginners) for high level tensorflow APIs. All Saving and Restoration a Tensorflow model tutorials make use of Low-level Tensorflow APIs, which support all these functionalities and many more (Sessions/Graphs/Summary etc. gracefully)

Just saw the comment after saving the answer, which also I think suggests similar thing, so not sure whether to keep mine or not. Still keeping it incase

Comment: Thanks for your input Kanishk.  I am back to this problem; had to move on to something else for a while.  I thought I got this but I am still lost.  I am trying to follow your answer to use "model = tf.estimator.Estimator"; but got stuck in "model_fn=<Your_Estimator_Function>".  Looks like defining model_fn using tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec is not simple either, because this take you to defining your own architecture etc.  Any pointers on how to create model_fn?

Comment: Hey @KRS, For your use case you can simply use _tf.estimator.DNNClassifier_ (provide the same checkpoint's path you used while training)<br>

For defining custom estimators (which will be used for Training as well as Testing phase), go through the tensorflow API document : https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/custom_estimators
It will take you some time to get accustomed, and clear the confusion b/w low-level vs high-level tensorflow apis, but is worth a try